# How to modify ID of controls in relative layout?

Tags: android-layout

I am new to Android and working with Relative Layout. Now I am trying to change the ID of  controls but as soon as I change the ID, other controls get re-positioned as they are relative to each other. Is their any way to change ID of controls without re-positioning them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because every object in your relative layout is arranged base on object ID. Once you changed one of the object ID, you will need to change its object ID on the other side as well. If not the layout will be pretty messed up and need to rearrange.

The best way to avoid this is to declare every object ID before you proceed.

My advice is that you changed the object ID one by one. Change all the field of the object ID to the latest.

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_email"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:text="@string/password_text" />


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/login_password"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login_email"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:password="true"
    android:singleLine="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/register_button"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="40dip"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/login_password"
    android:layout_below="@+id/login_password"
    android:text="@string/signup_text" />
```

For example, based on the code above, once you change the `TextView` id from `@+id/textView3` to `@+id/password_text`. You would need to change one by one in those object that contains the of `@+id/textView3` to `@+id/password_text`. Which is in

```
   <EditText
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
```

By the way try tag Android in your question as well. More people will notice your question that way.